# Как разделить список кортежей двух элементов на два отдельных списк? ("unzip")

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Есть список вида `[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]`. Как его **изящно** разделить на два вот таких списка?:

```
[1,3,5]
[2,4,6]
```

Вопрос не в том как это сделать, а есть ли готовая функция которая разделит их(что то типа "unzip")

Ну и на всяких случай код, как это делаю я:

```
tlist = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]

list1 = [a for a, _ in tlist]
list2 = [b for _, b in tlist]

print(list1, list2)
```

Хотелось бы вот так сделать:

```
list1, list2 = unzip(tlist, valuecount=2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [123]: items = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]

In [124]: a,b = list(zip(*items))

In [125]: a
Out[125]: (1, 3, 5)

In [126]: b
Out[126]: (2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: Спасибо) уже тоже нашел. но удалять не буду вопрос.

Comment: @garrythehotdog, это стандартный трюк, применяемый для транспонирования матрицы